# Why is socket.setNoDelay() throwing an error?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a nodejs server using socketio for real-time comms.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io')().listen(app)

function init() {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.setNoDelay(true);
    onSocketConnection(socket);
});
```

Issue is, every time I call socket.setNoDelay(true); it's kicking back:

```
E:[path]\server.js:58
  socket.setNoDelay(true);
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (E:\[path]\server.js:58:12)   
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Namespace.emit (E:\path]\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:205:10)   
    at E:\[path]\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:172:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I can't seem to find any documentation as to why this is happening. Anyone else see this?

Specs:

```
> Windows Environment  
> node version: 0.12.4 
> socket.io version: 1.3.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `socket` isn't a [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket), it's a [socket.io `Socket`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket).  You'll notice that there is no `setNoDelay` method on a socket.io `Socket`.

The socket.io websocket sever [automatically disables Nagle on the underlying TCP socket](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/0.7.1/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L234).

Comment: Good sleuthing to find that underlying `.setNoDelay()` call.  Does engine.io use that `github.com/websockets/ws` library that you linked?